# Suche Adjektiv oder Adverb, das die kraftvollen, eleganten Bewegungen eines Raubtieres beschreibt

Tags: single-word-request

Mir liegt ein Wort auf der Zunge, mit dem üblicherweise die Bewegung von Tieren, vor allem Raubtieren, beschrieben wird. Die Bedeutung ist ungefähr: "ästhetisch ansprechend, kraftvoll, anmutig, nicht trainiert sondern natürlich".

Wisst ihr so ein Wort?

Es kann natürlich sein, dass ich mich täusche, und es ein Wort mit dieser Bedeutung im Deutschen nicht gibt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Das gesuchte Wort ist möglicherweise *geschmeidig*, es erscheint im berühmten Gedicht *Der Panther* von Rilke:

> Der weiche Gang geschmeidig starker Schritte, ...

Comment: Das ist es, glaube ich, nicht ganz, aber trotzdem vielen Dank für deine Hilfe.

Answer (score 1):

Vielleicht eins von folgenden:

Galant,  unbeschwert, virtuos, meisterhaft, stolz, gekonnt, erhaben, schmiegsam